# having trouble with color in batch

Tags: batch-file, colors

I'm trying to make an option for my batch game to change the color using a variable, but It doesn't change, here's all the coding associated with the coloring, (heads up, it's pretty long,) did I do something wrong?

```
:colorchoice1
cls
color 8
set /a %cChoice% = 0
echo so, what color do you want?
echo.
echo 1) black (that'd make it pretty hard to see, huh?)
echo 2) blue
echo 3) green
echo 4) aqua
echo 5) red
echo 6) purple
echo 7) yellow
echo 8) white
echo 9) more options

set /p cChoice=
if %cChoice% == 1 color 0
goto confirmcolor
if %cChoice% == 2 color 1
goto confirmcolor
if %cChoice% == 3 color 2
goto confirmcolor
if %cChoice% == 4 color 3
goto confirmcolor
if %cChoice% == 5 color 4
goto confirmcolor
if %cChoice% == 6 color 5
goto confirmcolor
if %cChoice% == 7 color 6
goto confirmcolor
if %cChoice% == 8 color 7
goto confirmcolor
if %cChoice% == 9 goto colorchoice2
goto colorchoice1

:colorchoice2
cls
color 8
set /a %cChoice% = 0
echo so, what color do you want?
echo.
echo 10) grey (default)
echo 11) light blue
echo 12) light green
echo 13) light aqua
echo 14) light red (pink)
echo 15) light purple
echo 16) light yellow
echo 17) bright white
echo 18) back to other options
```

I feel like the problem is somewhere past this point

```
set /p cChoice=
if %cChoice% == 10 color 8
goto confirmcolor
if %cChoice% == 11 color 9
goto confirmcolor
if %cChoice% == 12 color A
goto confirmcolor
if %cChoice% == 13 color B
goto confirmcolor
if %cChoice% == 14 color C
goto confirmcolor
if %cChoice% == 15 color D
goto confirmcolor
if %cChoice% == 16 color E
goto confirmcolor
if %cChoice% == 17 color F
goto confirmcolor
if %cChoice% == 18 goto colorchoice1
goto colorchoice 2

:confirmcolor
cls
echo are you sure this is the color you want?
echo (remember, this cannot be changed later)
echo.
echo.
echo 1) yes
echo 2) no

set /p confcolor=
if %confcolor% == 1 goto name
if %confcolor% == 2 goto colorchoice1
goto confirmcolor
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using multiline `if` statements. Right now, you are only telling the `if` to run the command that is on the same line as the check. Because of this, the `goto confirmcolor` command that is under `if %cChoice% == 1 color 0` gets called *regardless of what choice was picked*.

There are two ways to fix this: You can either use parentheses to make multi-line `if` statements like this:

```
if %cChoice% == 1 (
    color 0
    goto confirmcolor
)
if %cChoice% == 2 (
    color 1
    goto confirmcolor
)
```

Or, because that's horribly redundant, you can just have one last check at the end of all the checks, like this:

```
set /p cChoice=
echo *%cChoice%* selected.
if %cChoice% == 1 color 0
if %cChoice% == 2 color 1
if %cChoice% == 3 color 2
if %cChoice% == 4 color 3
if %cChoice% == 5 color 4
if %cChoice% == 6 color 5
if %cChoice% == 7 color 6
if %cChoice% == 8 color 7
if %cChoice% == 9 goto colorchoice2
if %cChoice% lss 9 goto confirmcolor
goto colorchoice1
```